# Expansion using Taylor infinite series for F(x)

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Ques- Assuming the validity of expansion , show that $$f(x) = f(a) +2[\frac{(x-a)}{2}f'(\frac{x+a}{2}) +\frac{(x-a)^3}{8*3!}f'''(\frac{x+a}{2})+\frac{(x-1a)^5}{32*5!}f'''''(\frac{x+a}{2})+\cdots$$

Now I have calculated the expansion centered around x and( x+a)/2. After that I had differentiated the 2nd expansion, to get $f'((a+x)/2),f''((a+x)/2),...$ And calculating $f'(a), f''(a)$ from them.... For their substitution in Expansion centered at x but the equation I get after it  was  getting complicated.
Question proceeding incorrectly if yes please suggest the step to get desired result.

[image]

Comment: I have uploaded the image of the question  (circled one), for further clearance.

Comment: Now I have calculated the expansion centered around x and( x+a)/2. After that I had differentiated the 2nd expansion, to get f'((a+x)/2),f''((a+x)/2),... And calculating f'(a), f"(a).... For its substituion in Expansion centered at x but was unable to proof as equation was getting complicated

Comment: Sorry for mistake... Thank u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the definition of a taylor expansion as:

$$ f(x) = f(u) + \frac{1}{1}f'(u)(x-u) + \frac{1}{2!}f''(u)(x-u)^2 + .. $$

Let $u = \frac{x+a}{2}$. Then it naturally follows $x - u = \frac{x-a}{2}$

So we have generally

$$ f(x) = f \left( \frac{x+a}{2} \right) + \frac{1}{1!}\left(\frac{x-a}{2}\right) f'\left( \frac{x+a}{2} \right) + \frac{1}{2!} \left( \frac{x-a}{2}\right)^2f''\left( \frac{x+a}{2}\right) + ... $$

And by symmetry
$$  f(a) = f \left( \frac{x+a}{2} \right) + \frac{1}{1!}\left(\frac{a-x}{2}\right) f'\left( \frac{x+a}{2} \right) + \frac{1}{2!} \left( \frac{a-x}{2}\right)^2f''\left( \frac{x+a}{2}\right) + ... $$

But we can now equate out $(a-x)^{2n+1} =-(x-a)^{2n+1}$ on odd powers $2n+1$, and observe that $(a-x)^{2n} = (x-a)^{2n}$ for even powers $2n$. So we rewrite our series:

$$ f(a) = f \left( \frac{x+a}{2} \right) - \frac{1}{1!}\left(\frac{x-a}{2}\right) f'\left( \frac{x+a}{2} \right) + \frac{1}{2!} \left( \frac{x-a}{2}\right)^2f''\left( \frac{x+a}{2}\right) + ... $$

Now lets take their difference

$$ f(x) - f(a) = 2 \left( \frac{1}{1!}\left(\frac{x-a}{2}\right) f'\left( \frac{x+a}{2} \right) + \frac{1}{3!} \left( \frac{x-a}{2}\right)^3f''\left( \frac{x+a}{2}\right) + ... \right) $$

And then move from right side to left side to get our final answer:

$$ f(x) = f(a) +   2 \left( \frac{1}{1!}\left(\frac{x-a}{2}\right) f'\left( \frac{x+a}{2} \right) + \frac{1}{3!} \left( \frac{x-a}{2}\right)^3f''\left( \frac{x+a}{2}\right) + ... \right)$$